# installing ubuntu from disk and few other quesions

Tags: preinstallation

So I decided to finally download ubuntu, I notice the file is an .iso, does that mean I need to decompress it before burning it to a disk? That can be done with something like winrar, yes? Or does windowsxp already have something to decompress files? What program would you recommend using to burn it and at what write speed? I was thinking of going with cdburnerxp.

**strong text**I tried infra recorder and cdburnerxp- both aren't working, is it because I'm using windowsxp in safe mode?**strong text**

Comment: no if you are using windows, simply right click on it and burn disk , thats it

Comment: You just need to burn the iso to disk, (you have probably gathered that already), but for Windows the [Win32 Disk Imager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) is useful, particularly for USB sticks.

Answer (score 0):

No decompressing must not be done. If done, most probably it won't be bootable.

For burning 
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows,

If you want to use usb follow http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

`.iso` is a disk image format - it's like whole DVD disk held in a single file. You can burn it with cdburnerxp - use option "burn ISO image":

[image: cdburnerxp burn iso]

Answer (score 0):

Its already on internet , google it before making question , well I am summarising it here the steps -

Assuming that you are working with Windows7 for making bootable Ubuntu Installation DVD

1.Download or obtain an ISO File.

2.Right click on the ISO file.

3.Click "Burn disc image".

4.Select the appropriate drive for burning the disc and click the burn button.

Thats it your Bootable DVD is ready for installation with using any third party software means with simply Windows. Enjoy Ubuntu!!